# Rails 3.2 config.cache_classes = true results blank values in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a template (show.html.erb) which submits adjustment requests. Also in the template I have a table that breaks down Pending Adjustments and Completed Adjustments that show you information about the adjustment you just submited.  EX. type, reason, created at.

When I set config.cache_classes = true in my environments/development.rb the Pending Adjustments and Completed Adjustments table the values dont show except for the created at timestamp.  The type or reason do not show.  If I set config.cache_classes = false everything appears.  I've also set config.action_view.cache_template_loading = false and still get the same results empty table values.

I am trying to get it to work with config.cache_classes = true because in production I need the caching to be turned on for other things.

#### controllers/print_cost_controller.rb

```
class PrintCostController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @printcost = PrintCost.find(params[:id])
    @order = Core::Order.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :show, @order
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :show }
    end
  end
end
```

#### models/printcost.rb

```
class PrintCost < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = ENV["PRINT_COST_URL"]
  @headers  = { 'Authorization' => "Token token=#{ENV['PRINT_COST_TOKEN']}" }
end
```

#### show.html.erb

```
<% if !@printcost.adjustments.empty? %>
  <div class="adjustments_pending">
    <h4 class="printcost">Pending Adjustments</h4>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Requested On</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    <% @printcost.adjustments.each do |adjustment| %>
      <% if adjustment.completed_at == nil %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= DateTime.parse(adjustment.created_at).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%^b-%d-%y %I:%M:%S %P") %></td>
          <td><%= adjustment.explanation %></td>
          <td><%= adjustment.adjustment_type %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'X', remove_adjustment_path(adjustment.id), :method => :delete, :class => "badge", "data-title" =>"Cancel Request" %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div class="adjustments_completed">
    <h4 class="printcost">Completed Adjustments</h4>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Requested On</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Note</th>
      </tr>
      <% @printcost.adjustments.each do |adjustment| %>
        <% if adjustment.completed_at %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= DateTime.parse(adjustment.completed_at).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%^b-%d-%y %I:%M:%S %P") %></td>
            <td><%= adjustment.adjustment_type == "Tax" ? "$#{adjustment.adjustment_cost} - #{adjustment.explanation}" : adjustment.explanation %></td>
            <td><%= adjustment.adjustment_type %></td>
            <td><%= adjustment.note %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  It was an issue with another model I had called Adjustments.  Had to rename some things.